# Where is Schema data saved in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am saving some data with Mongoose but unsure where it is saved. Where is this data saved in MongoDb? In which table or collection?

```
var Chat = mongoose.model('Chat', ChatSchema);

console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
var data = [{
  sent: new Date(),
  room: 'General',
  username: 'Chris',
  text: msg
}]
//Loop through each of the chat data and insert into the database
for (var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
  //Create an instance of the chat model
  var entry = new Chat(data[c]);
  //Call save to insert the chat
  entry.save(function(err, savedChat) {
    console.log(savedChat);
  });
}
```

Comment: It should be saved in whatever collection you specified in moose

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name.

Check the documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html (option: collection)

In your case if you connect to the database you will see a collection: `chats`